# How can I position the window's position on startup to the right side of the user's screen?

Tags: c#, wpf, window, location, sidebar

I am currently creating a sidebar-like WPF application in C#. When a user starts the application, I would like the window to automatically position it's self to the side of the user's screen. I have tried a few methods and google searches, but have not found any help.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

http://prntscr.com/5tfkz

How can I efficiently go about achieving something like this?

---

@dknaack

I tried this code:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            this.Left = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Right - this.Width;
            this.Top = 0;
            this.Height = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height;

        }
```

and got the following errors:

Error   1   The type 'System.Drawing.Size' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.  C:\Users\Test\Documents\Expression\Blend 4\Projects\WindBar_Prototype_1\WindBar_Prototype_1\MainWindow.xaml.cs  32  13  WindBar_Prototype_1

and

Error   2   'System.Drawing.Size' does not contain a definition for 'Width' and no extension method 'Width' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Drawing.Size' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\Users\Test\Documents\Expression\Blend 4\Projects\WindBar_Prototype_1\WindBar_Prototype_1\MainWindow.xaml.cs  32  78  WindBar_Prototype_1

Any help?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### Description

You can use `Screen` from `System.Windows.Forms`.

So add reference to the `System.Windows.Forms.dll` and `System.Drawing.dll`. Then change the `Left` and `Height` property in the `MainWindow_Loaded` method.

#### Sample

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainWindow_Loaded);
}

void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Left = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Right - this.Width;
    this.Top = 0;
    this.Height = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height;
}
```

#### More Information

- [MSDN - Screen Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.aspx)

Comment: @JamesDidzun Did you referenced `System.Drawing.dll` too ?

Comment: Okay, I just tried that, and I didn't have any trouble building it anymore. The only problem is, it's not on the side of the screen! Look: http://prntscr.com/5th4q -  Thank again

Comment: Looks like the event gets not fired. You can set a breakpoint to see if the method get called. Check out my updated answer `this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainWindow_Loaded);`

Comment: Actually, I figured out the problem. I had some empty space in the window... Haha. Thanks for your help!  -Best Answer-

Comment: One more thing... How can I get the side bar on to the right side instead of the left?

Comment: I think you mean on the left instead the right ? In my answer your window is on the right side of the primary screen.

Comment: Are you sure that `MainWindow_Loaded` get called ? Set a breakpoint please.

Comment: Nevermind...  I somehow fixed it... Thanks for all of your help, dknaack. Regards, James

Comment: Where is this method or event located?

Answer (score 5):

You can do this without referencing win forms assemblies by using `SystemParameters`. In the code behind for your window XAML:

```
MainWindow() {
    InitializeComponents();

    this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(
      delegate(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args) {
        Width = 300;
        Left = SystemParameters.VirtualScreenLeft;
        Height = SystemParameters.VirtualScreenHeight;
    }
}
```

[SystemParameters documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters.aspx)

Comment: `System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen` is better for the situations you have more than 1 screen

Comment: How is it better MikroDel?
I'm using a tripple monitor setup, two side by side, and the third one is above the two right in the middle.
With SystemParameters I actually got everything I needed.

Answer (score 2):

in your xaml :

```
WindowStartupLocation="Manual"
```

in the constructor :

```
 Left = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth - Width
 Top=0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.Manual;
    Left =  System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize.Width - Width;
}
```

Comment: `WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.Manual;` is a good hint

Answer (score 0):

use startPosition property or location property

Comment: The startPosition property does not have a side-of-screen location

Comment: I can't try the code now, but isn't there in the form's class a this.position property, where you can set custom points ? like: this.position =new Point(x,y) ?

Comment: @yoz cia The question is about WPF Window.

Comment: private void SetWindowPosition(){ Left = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth - (double)GetValue(WidthProperty); Top = 0; }

Answer (score -1):

```
<body>
<script>
function myfunc()
{
    w1=window.open('http://www.google.com','Google','left=0,top=0,width=250px,height=250px');
    w2=window.open('http://www.yahoomail.com','Yahoo Mail','left=1166,top=0,width=250px,height=250px');
    w3=window.open('http://www.people.com','People Magazine','left=1166,top=500,width=250px,height=250px');
    w4=window.open('http://www.time.com','Time Magazines','left=0,top=500,width=250px,height=250px');
    w5=window.open('http://www.ew.com','Entertainment Weekly','left=550,top=250,width=250px,height=250px');

}

function myclose()
{
 w1.close(); w2.close(); w3.close(); w4.close(); w5.close();
 w6=window.open('smartwindow.html',' mywindow',',');
}
</script>
    <div id="cover">
    <img src="images/abstract.jpeg" id="1" width="500px" height="400px" alt="color defined"onClick="myfunc()"/>
     <input type="button" value="click to close all windows" onClick="myclose()"/>
     </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Huh? This is HTML, not XAML/WPF/C#. You need to read the question, not just the title.