# How can I set the Windows position on startup

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, windows-10-universal

I want to set the position of the window on the right side on the screen similar to [WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9120950/how-can-i-position-the-windows-position-on-startup-to-the-right-side-of-the-use). Is there a way in UWP to do this?

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK it's not possible in *UWP* (at least not yet), you can change window size or make it fullscreen by accessing [ApplicationView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.aspx) class, but there are no such methods/properties like in *WPF*.

There was also [similar question on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/925db0d5-3d0b-446b-8a7f-61c32d8a522f/uwp-window-placement?forum=wpdevelop).

Answer (score -6):

Yes there is a way :) Go to your xaml for example Windows1.xaml

then put this there. Example code

```
 <Window
x:Class="Poultry_Management_System.Window1"      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Login"
Width="450"
WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
WindowStyle="None"
ResizeMode="NoResize"
Topmost="True"
KeyDown="keyDown_form"
Height="200">
```

As you can see my StartupLocation there is in the Center.

Comment: Thanks for answering! What if I want to set the Window location programmatically?

Comment: Well then you should read about event base actions thoroughly. There are many example about that

Comment: Are you sure this is for *UWP*?

Comment: By the way, your solution is also for WPF, UWP uses <Application> and <Page> :)

Comment: @RandomUser Where in *<Application>* or *<Page>* in *UWP* is *WindowStartupLocation*?

Comment: @Romasz, I coudn't find the property anywhere, I think it's a <Window> only property.

Comment: This doesn't work in UWP. It's for WPF. UWP does have a class `Window`, but it cannot be declared in XAML and doesn't have such properties as `Topmost` or `WindowStartupLocation`, or `ResizeMode`